# A married couple

Tags: cipher

*Disclaimer:* This puzzle is from a university in Israel, computer science. Its in a real document written in Hebrew so no point in posting it. There is no link to it on the internet.

There is a couple that has been married for 10 years. It all started when the husband wrote this cipher to his wife.

```
91
21
62
62
21
23
63
61
32
82
71
33
63
73
21
23
63
33
33
32
32
?
```

The answer is supposed to be in English.

Comment: There is no more context....a couple is married for 10 years, they met at a restaurant and the guy wrote to her this. I don't know the answer but this is the only context i got.

Comment: Thanks for telling us about the source! Is this part of some sort of competition or challenge the university department is running?

Comment: Just something our lecturer gave us as a "bonus" assignment in a test (no points) but never revealed the answer to us.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 27):

So, here is the *key* to solve this:

> [image]

The number $XY$ represents:

> Pressing $X$ button $Y$ times.
>  For example, $91$ is W and $21$ is A.

So the answer is:

> WANNA COME UP FOR A COFFEE?

Comment: That. Is. Impressive.

Comment: Ya give that puzzle to your wife to solve, she will ban you from going for a coffee with her for entire life time!