# Find my name from this list of symbols

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

From the symbols below, find my name?

> # ! # @  * @ & \$ ^ # * # \$ #

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 1:

> Look at your PC keyboard. Try to type the symbols without pressing shift key.
>  We will have **31328274638343**.

Step 1.5:

> Arrange the numbers in pairs.
>  We will have **31 32 82 74 63 83 43**.

Step 2:

> Look at your phone keypad. Try to type an SMS like an old-school where XY means tapping X button Y times.
>  We will have, one and only, **Deusovi**.

Comment: wow... worked towards step 1.5, but not 2... well done genius!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton haha thanks, but I prefer to be said lucky as I solved the code with similar technique recently ^^: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84254/a-married-couple/84258#84258

Comment: Unfortunately this requires an American keyboard layout to even figure out (compare with a [German layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/KB_Germany.svg/2000px-KB_Germany.svg.png) for example).

Comment: Nice! I didn't get the last step, I thought maybe the pairs were Ascii code for the letters but ended up with   RJ?S+, probably not right...